# how to get average ms time

Tags: python

when i do this

```
result = subprocess.run(['ping', '8.8.8.8'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

print(result)
```

I get something like this

```
CompletedProcess(args=['ping', '8.8.8.8'], returncode=0, stdout=b'\r\nPinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:\r\nReply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=118\r\nReply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=118\r\nReply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=118\r\nReply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=118\r\n\r\nPing statistics for 8.8.8.8:\r\n    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),\r\nApproximate 
round trip times in milli-seconds:\r\n    Minimum = 3ms, Maximum = 3ms, Average = 3ms\r\n')
```

How do i get only the average ping time?

I tried other ways to ping but they returned the same

Comment: You will need to parse the output in any case so I don't see how skipping some parts of it will be helpful?

Comment: re.search('.*Average = (\d+)ms.*', txt).group(1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String manipulation is really easy and powerful in Python. You can do something like:

```py
result = subprocess.run(['ping', '8.8.8.8'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
avg_time_ms = int(f'{result}'.replace('\r\n', '').split('Average = ')[1].split('ms')[0]))
print(f'Average time was {avg_time_ms} ms.')
```